# Spring Boot application failure - Error java package does not exist

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, maven-plugin

I'm having a Spring Boot project referring to an external module to execute the results.

[image]

I have already added the external module under module dependencies:

[image]

However when I run the Spring Boot application, it fails with this error:
`Error:(3, 16) java: package examples does not exist`

[image]

`CustomerLossPrediction` in the below source referring to external module and call to this module fails even though I added the module to project workspace and dependencies are added correctly.

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import examples.CustomerLossPrediction;
import org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

@Service
public class DL4JServiceImpl implements DL4JService {
    @Override
    public String fetchPrediction(MultipartFile file) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        File convFile = new File( file.getOriginalFilename());
        file.transferTo(convFile);
        INDArray array = new CustomerLossPrediction().generateOutput(convFile);
        return array.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is the `pom.xml` if needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>nd4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>exec</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I'm thinking it happens because I tried to refer an external module that is some way or the other cannot refer from Spring Boot module?

Comment: Have you specified the bean in the component annotation tag ?

Comment: `CustomerLossPrediction` isn't a spring bean, it's a plain java class on external module.

Comment: Can you run main method through IDE? Like opening the DemoApplication.java file in IntelliJ and click the green button appearing on the left bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add that external module as maven dependency. If you fail to do so, even if you manage to run it from IDE, it will fail to build with Maven.

Here you have explained how to install JAR as Maven artifact. When you do that, include it as dependency in POM

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: Thanks for the great info. Quick question, is it possible to add a directory dependency or something like that without needing to create a jar out of external module?

Comment: I don't know that, never needed it. JAR is natural distribution package, so what you would try to do would be unusual in entire ecosystem. Either add sources to your main project, or create JAR of dependency and add via maven.

Comment: Just followed your steps. Created a jar from external module. Selected the only class (main) where  all implementation+ main method is present. Here is the command: `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=dl4j.jar -DgroupId=dl4j -DartifactId=dl4j -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar`. Then jar file dependency is added in the pom.xml file. But now when I execute the spring boot application, I get this error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: examples.CustomerLossPrediction`

Comment: Did you add it to POM ?

Comment: Yes, I added :(

Comment: If you have sources of that "external module" you can just include it in your sources.

Comment: Here is the pom.xml:
https://gist.github.com/rahul-raj/7b7005560ac5288252dc3ec6caa4153d

Comment: Do `mvn clean install`, can do the same from IDE.

Comment: you mean `mvn clean install:install-file -Dfile=dl4j.jar -DgroupId=dl4j -DartifactId=dl4j -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar`?

Comment: No just mvn clean install in project directory.

Comment: Still the same problem while performing upload operation.
Here is the error log:
https://gist.github.com/rahul-raj/8acbaf11af4e7f34554000828c981c34

Comment: Idk you are doing something wrong. Check the JAR if it contains given dependency. It should fail on compile time if class was not there. Since it didnt.....